# Failing to fetch product collection for a given category

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I've written a method that I'm calling from my list.phtml file.
The logic should simply output the number of products in the currently viewed category and the highest and lowest prices. Pretty straight forward really.

For reasons beyond my understanding it's always returning that the current category contains no products, and I can't figure out why but I presume it's because I'm not fetching the product collection correctly.

Here's the code for my method.

```
    public function writeCatInfo(){
       if(Mage::registry('current_category')){
            $_productCollection=$this->getLoadedProductCollection;
            $catname = Mage::registry('current_category')->getName();
            $priceArray = array();
            foreach ($_productCollection as $_product){
                $priceArray[] = $_product->getSpecialPrice();
            }
            $numItems = count($_productCollection);
            $highPrice = number_format(max($priceArray),2);
            $lowPrice = number_format(min($priceArray),2);
            $infostring =  ucwords($catname)." contains ".$numItems." products with prices ranging from £".$lowPrice." to £".$highPrice;
            echo $infostring;
        }   
    }
```

Comment: parenthesis missing in calling `getLoadedProductCollection` method. Hope it will help.

Comment: adding the parethesis produces a "Fatal error: Call to undefined method " error.

Comment: where,you write this function writeCatInfo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out my helper was extending the wrong class - `Mage_Core_Helper_Abtract` instead of `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List`. Changing this fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

this will help you to get current category product collection.

```
$category_id = Mage::getModel('catalog/layer')->getCurrentCategory()->getId();
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category_id);
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addCategoryFilter($category)
    ->setOrder('price', 'ASC')
    ->load();
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see the below code to get product collection by Category id

$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category_id)

->getProductCollection()

->addAttributeToSelect('*') // add all attributes - optional

->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1) // enabled

->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', 4) //visibility in catalog,search

->setOrder('price', 'ASC'); //sets the order by price